# Node-pre-gyp and bcrypt yarn install problem on MacOS M1 Mac

Tags: macos, bcrypt, apple-m1, node-gyp, node-pre-gyp

I had to install bcrypt, but fell into errors. I tried most of the solutions I found. There are many threads, but I haven't seen many of them for Mac.
Here is what I've got from my terminal:

```
yarn install v1.22.11
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
info No lockfile found.
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
warning @types/date-fns@2.6.0: This is a stub types definition for date-fns (https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns). date-fns provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/date-fns installed!
warning @types/knex@0.16.1: This is a stub types definition. knex provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
warning knex > liftoff > findup-sync > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning knex > liftoff > findup-sync > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning sequelize > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning @types/otplib@10.0.0: This is a stub types definition. otplib provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
[3/5]   Fetching packages...
[4/5]   Linking dependencies...
[5/5]   Building fresh packages...
[1/4] ⢀ bcrypt
[2/4] ⢀ core-js
[3/4] ⢀ nodemon
error /Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.5
node-pre-gyp info using node@16.8.0 | darwin | arm64
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.0.1 and node@16.8.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@16.8.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@16.8.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
(node:7991) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
gyp info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/raydman/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/raydman/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.8.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/raydman/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.8.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@16.8.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'inf/backend/node_modules/node-addon-api'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v16.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.8.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.5
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/raydman/Projects/main inf/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/Users/rayd
```

As you can see it checked my python 2,7 also I'm using node v16.8.0. The error comes after I do `yarn install`. Same with `yarn add bcrypt` and `bcryptjs`.

Comment: I realize there are no prebuilt binaries for ARM, but doesn't bcrypt try to build from source on ARM?  In ARM linux if I have *build-essential*, it just builds from source.  all I have to do is `apt-get install build-essential` and `npm install bcrypt --save`.  IDK about mac, sorry, but for sure bcrypt works on ARM64 linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there are no versions for Mac M1 processors with ARM architecture. So anybody who wants to use bcrypt for those Macs, you have to install bcryptjs.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that your path contains a space or a special character. From what I see `main inf` has a space try moving your project to somewhere without a space or rename the space to a `-` that solved my problem on an M1 Pro mac had the exact same issue in my case I had -=Projects=- in my path as a folder name that was causing an issue.

[More info on GitHub](https://github.com/verebes1/node.bcrypt.js/tree/M1-Apple-Troubleshooting#troubleshooting-on-apple-m1-macs)