# "../bcrypt_lib.node' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64)))" while running tests

Tags: macos-monterey

[image: 1]

```
Error: dlopen(/Users//Documents/Work/Repo/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node, 0x0001): tried: '/Users//Documents/Work/Repo/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64)))
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/Work/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users//Documents/Work/Repo///node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:431:14)
```

any idea how to resolve this issue, new here. please let me know any additional info needed here.

Comment: follow [this](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/917) github issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered a similar error and what worked for me was upgrading my node version to a higher one. I was getting the error on node version `v14.16.1` but then upgraded to `v16.16.0` and the issue disappeared. Also, If you are using Mac M1, maybe make sure that you are using rosetta.

Comment: "maybe make sure that you are using rosetta."
do you mean i'll need to open my IDE using Rosetta?

Answer (score 4):

Reinstall node modules worked for me.

`rm -rf node_modules && npm i`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you cannot use bcrypt on M1 macs yet instead you will have to use bcryptjs.

As mentioned by @Dmitry Bochok [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69277347/8122338)

You can read more about the differences between bcrypt and bcryptjs
[How do Node's bcrypt and bcryptjs libraries differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674387/how-do-nodes-bcrypt-and-bcryptjs-libraries-differ)

Replacing bcrypt with bcryptjs worked for me on MBA M1.

Answer (score 1):

In my case what worked was actually to use an older version of Node by using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). That way I could use Node v14 instead of Node v16 that I had installed. It kind of makes sense as it was an app that I created some time ago and probably used Node v14 back then. Nvm is really useful to switch between Node versions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same issue in my M1 Mac; if changing the node version does not help(it did not help me), check your package.json file. Make use that you have "^" before your bycrypt dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you are using a node version manager like nvm.  The node version I was running during debug mode was different than when I would run in development ('npm run dev'), production, or even through 'npm run test'.  You can confirm your node version during a debug session and the command 'process.version'.

To fix the node version during debugging in VS Code, I updated the launch.json for my debugging environment.  Use "runtimeVersion": "20.11.0" to specify your node version.  Here's my complete launch.json:

```json
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Jest Test",
    "program": 
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "args": ["--runInBand"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "runtimeVersion": "20.11.0",
    "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The instalation of the modules were done in a mac m1 chip, and then i opened the repository in intel chip and got this error.
I simply delete all the node_modules and npm install.